# python-pip yum package provides pip-python instead of pip

Tags: python, fedora, distribute

I installed `python-pip` package via `yum` (using Fedora's updates repo). It does not add the `pip` script to my `PATH` though.

```
$ which pip
/usr/bin/which: no pip in
                (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:
                 /usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)
```

It does, however, create `pip-python`:

```
$ rpm -ql python-pip
/usr/bin/pip-python
[...snip...]

$ which pip-python
/usr/bin/pip-python
```

I was considering making `pip` a symbolic link to `pip-python` but is there a reason the executable is named `pip-python` to begin with?

Comment: I would consider a shell alias instead of a symbolic link.

Comment: Ah yes, alias would definitely make more sense.

Comment: **Update**: Installing `python-pip` on Fedora 17 or later, will create `/usr/bin/pip`. This question is not longer relevant today. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18455355/439427

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is probably to avoid a conflict with another package that has an executable called `pip`.  As long as you don't install that package, you should be safe.

Another annoying example of this is the chromium browser, which my distro's executable is `chromium-browser` to avoid a conflict with some game I had never heard of until I did an: `apt-get install chromium`.

Comment: That's it! Fedora has a package called "perl-pip". That **must** be the conflict. Thank you sir/ma'm.

Answer (score 35):

If you install the `python-pip` package and then run:

```
pip-python install -U pip
```

pip will fix itself.

Comment: You mean: pip-python install -U pip :)

Comment: yes, was conveying the idea, not the proper syntax.  fixed. :)

Answer (score 5):

This used to be the case on Fedora, due to the conflict noted with the perl-pip package. With the gracious consent of the perl-pip packager, this has been updated in recent versions, so installing pip-python on Fedora 17 or later now installs `/usr/bin/pip`

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=958377 for details.